# Какой знак препинания надо поставить?

Tags: пунктуация

Родиона мучает вопрос, кто он на самом деле(?) "тварь дрожащая" или "право имеет"?

Какое правило объяснит эту пунктуацию? Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Родиона мучает вопрос, ктО он на самом деле ―  "твАрь дрожащая" или "прАво имеет".**

1) Это тема обобщающего слова (кто) при однородных членах, надо выбирать между двоеточием (основной вариант) и тире (заменяет двоеточие), что следует из правил.

2) В данном предложении лучше  выбрать **тире**, чтобы обеспечить **ударение на ключевых словах** без понижения тона. (При двоеточии обязательно понижение тона и увеличенная предупредительная пауза).

3) Знак вопроса факультативный, здесь может быть и точка, так как это косвенная речь.

Comment: Спасибо большое!